# Youtube upload api

Tags: python, youtube, youtube-data-api

Does anybody here have any experience in using the YouTube API? I'm currently trying to automate uploading my videos by having an OAuth application, but, because its not verified, my videos get locked instantly and set to private. I cannot get my OAuth application verified due to not having a website.

Is there any other way I can do this without using an OAuth application?

```
def uploadClip(clip):
# Disable OAuthlib's HTTPS verification when running locally.
# *DO NOT* leave this option enabled in production.
os.environ["OAUTHLIB_INSECURE_TRANSPORT"] = "1"

api_service_name = "youtube"
api_version = "v3"
client_secrets_file = "client_secrets.json"

# Get credentials and create an API client
flow = google_auth_oauthlib.flow.InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file(client_secrets_file, scopes)
credentials = flow.run_console()
youtube = googleapiclient.discovery.build(api_service_name, api_version, credentials=credentials)

request = youtube.videos().insert(
    part="snippet,status",
    body={
        "snippet": {
            "categoryId": "22",
            "description": ".",
            "title": "H "
        },
        "status": {
            "privacyStatus": "public"
        }
    },

    # TODO: For this request to work, you must replace "YOUR_FILE"
    #       with a pointer to the actual file you are uploading.
    media_body=clip
)
response = request.execute()
```

Comment: The answer to your question is: *no, there's not other way, but to get your app verified by Google.* But you may still upload videos manually, via the YouTube's Web UI.

Comment: It just seems really over the top to require authorisation which takes up to 6 weeks for a simple personal project, and why would they require you to have a website? It seems very strict for something which is such a simple and useful task.

Comment: Sorry, am not a Google employee, thus am not trying to justify that company's choices. I'm only stating that, from the perspective of an API user, the API has not such concept as *simple personal project.*

Comment: I agree that YouTube has made this process overly complex. It is meant for large corporations with big IT departments. Not mom and pop businesses with minimal IT knowledge. Even getting the app verified is no easy task . They don't take time to understand what your app does. Instead they reply back with tons of copy/pasted information which often just makes you more confused.